# setTimeout() и стэк

Tags: javascript, async-await

разбираюсь с debouncing и throttling, основу работы setTimeout() и setInterval() понимаю, но код ниже меня запутывает, так при выполнении без пауз в Node.js и хроме выдает (1, 3, 4), а при разборе выполнения кода с паузами в режиме отладки в хроме выдает(1, 3).

Не пойму, когда именно срабатывает setTimeout() внутри и вне функции. Могут ли они выполняться в одно время, то есть походу выполнения включается другой?

```js
function f(x) {
    console.log(x);
}

function debounce(func, ms) {
    let isCooldown = false;

    return function() {

        if (isCooldown === false) {
            func.apply(this, arguments);
            isCooldown = true;
        }

        setTimeout(() => isCooldown = false, ms);
    };
}


let f1000 = debounce(f, 1000);

f1000(1); // сразу выполняется
f1000(2); // активирует таймер, в котором через 1с будет "true"

setTimeout(() => f1000(3), 1100);// по идее этот вызов должен сработать наверняка - вывести 3.
setTimeout(() => f1000(4), 2110);// а этот вызов лишь задать "false" для последующих.
```